# How to installation PHPRedmin?

Tags: php, redis, phpredis, predis

I m trying to install *phpRedMin* and having some issues with that. All the documentation I found were available for older version of *Apache.*

I am using *Apache version 2.4.7*  in Ubuntu and I am not able to locate

```
Apache configuration example (/etc/httpd/conf.d/phpredmin.conf)
```

Can any one help with how to installation it?

Answer (score 0):

I just was able to get it up and running on my Ubuntu Server 14.04.4 with php7 installed from this repo **ppa:ondrej/php**, https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php

First I compiled the phpredis PHP module so PHP apps can comunicate with the REDIS server. Please have in mind that this steps are for PHP7, if you use PHP5 Ubuntu packages, then adjust it to fit your packages. I think you could do that simply by checkout the phpredmin master branch and not the PHP 7 one.

```
sudo su
apt-get update
apt-get install git build-essential tcl8.5 php-pear php7.0-dev
git clone -b php7 https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis.git
cd phpredis/
phpize
./configure
make && make install
touch /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/redis.ini
echo 'extension=redis.so' > /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/redis.ini
phpenmod redis
service apache2 restart
```

Then you install PHPRedmin

```
cd /var/www
git clone https://github.com/sasanrose/phpredmin.git
mkdir -p ./phpredis/logs/apache2handler/
chown www-data ./phpredmin/ -R
```

Create the apache config file

```
nano /etc/apache2/conf-available/phpredmin.conf
```

And then paste this apache config in that file. Change the allowed ips as loy like.

```
# phpredmin - Simple web interface to manage and monitor your Redis

Alias /phpredmin /var/www/phpredmin/public

<Directory /var/www/phpredmin/>
   AllowOverride All 

   <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.4
     <RequireAny>
       Require ip 10.0.0
       Require ip 127.0.0.1
       Require local
     </RequireAny>
   </IfModule>

   <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.2
     Order Deny,Allow
     Deny from All
     Allow from 10.0.0.*
     Allow from 127.0.0.1
     Allow from ::1
   </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

Then enable that conf and restart apache

```
a2enconf phpredmin
service apache2 restart
```

You can access the interface through http://server.com/phpredmin

Hope it helps. Gerads!